# Escaping characters in entry.postDate|date

Tags: datetime

`{{ entry.postDate|date('jS F Y \at ga') }}`This should produce this `5th November 2016 at 4am`but it doesn't seem to recognise the escape and adds 30 instead of at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll actually need to add a double backwards slash in front of each character you want to escape, i.e.

```
{{ entry.postDate|date('jS F Y \\a\\t ga') }}
```

See [the official Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html#date) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Mats, I followed the php date reference [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in our Craft manual...